# AccumulatingFiredPanes in apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

If I use accumulatingFiredPanes in apache beam code, how long are the fired panes accumulated? Are they discarded at the end of the window? What are the storage implications for using accumulatingFiredPanes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly correct--the contents of the window is accumulated (and the running contents released in each pane) until the window is finished. The storage implications depend on the lifetime of the window (and the rate of data coming in), e.g. if you have very large windows (days or weeks) it could be considerable. The global window will never finish.

Note that if a combiner is used, only the combined value will be stored rather than storing all the elements individually.